# How to plott the learning curve of bias-variance tradeoff?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

Lm using LIBSVM with MatLab interface to classify 34x5 data in 3 classes. I applied 10 fold Kfold cross validation method and RBF kernel. The output is this confusion matrix with 0.88 Correct rate (88 % accuracy). I would like to increase the accuracy and get is possible pure diagonal confusion matrix. This is the code

```
load Turn180SVM1; //load data file
libsvm_options = '-s 1 -t 2 -d 3 -r 0 -c 1 -n 0.1 -p 0.1 -m 100 -e 0.000001 -h 1 -b 0 -wi 1 -q';//svm options

C=size(Turn180SVM1,2);

% cross validation
for i = 1:10
    indices = crossvalind('Kfold',Turn180SVM1(:,C),10);
    cp = classperf(Turn180SVM1(:,C)); 
    for j = 1:10
        [X, Z] = find(indices(:,end)==j);%testing
        [Y, Z] = find(indices(:,end)~=j);%training


feature_training = Turn180SVM1([Y'],[1:C-1]); feature_testing = Turn180SVM1([X'],[1:C-1]);
class_training = Turn180SVM1([Y'],end); class_testing = Turn180SVM1([X'], end);
% SVM Training
       disp('training');
       [feature_training,ps] = mapminmax(feature_training',0,1);
       feature_training = feature_training';
       feature_testing = mapminmax('apply',feature_testing',ps)';
       model = svmtrain(class_training,feature_training,libsvm_options);  
% 

% SVM Prediction       
        disp('testing');
        TestPredict = svmpredict(class_testing,sparse(feature_testing),model);
       TestErrap = sum(TestPredict~=class_testing)./length(class_testing)*100;
         cp = classperf(cp, TestPredict, X);
        disp(((i-1)*10 )+j);
end;
end;
[ConMat,order] = confusionmat(TestPredict,class_testing);
cp.CorrectRate;
cp.CountingMatrix;
```

First, I would like to plot the learning curve of bias-variance tradeoff. Any help or which command is used to plot the learning curve?
And than how to plot the ROC also?
Any help or code example of both cases?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't downvote, but without some code it hard to tell what you understand and what you're stuck on. Can you do plots in Matlab?

Comment: I post the code. Yes, I can do plots in Matlab